# Switch bottom tabs from drawer navigation

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, stack-navigator, react-navigation-drawer

*:- i have bottom tabs => (home, list, data). 
*:- i have one drawer navigation.
*:- i wants to add (home, list, data) in drawer navigation as well.
*:- and then i wants to trigger tab change from drawer navigation.
*:- let suppose if i click on list or data item from drawer it should call event and change bottom tabs

My Code

```jsx
const tabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  HomeStack,
  UserStack,
  LinksStack,
  SettingsStack
});

const AppStack = createStackNavigator(
  { Main: tabNavigator },
  {
    headerMode: "none"
  }
);

const DrawerNav = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: AppStack
  },
  {
    contentComponent: props => (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <View
          style={{
            height: 100,
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "center",
            background: "#5cb7e6"
          }}
        ></View>
        <ScrollView>
          <DrawerItems {...props} />
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    )
  }
);



const AuthStack = createStackNavigator  (
  { SignIn: Login },
  {
    headerMode: "none"
  }
);



export default createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
      App: DrawerNav,
      Auth: AuthStack
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: "AuthLoading",
      defaultNavigationOptions: {
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#0082c6"
        },
        headerTintColor: "#fff",
        headerLayoutPreset: "center",
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight: "bold"
        }
      }
    }
  )
);
```

Comment: Can you try to rewrite your question? I don't understand what you want to accomplish

Comment: *:- i have bottom tabs => (home, list, data). 
*:- i have one drawer navigation.
*:- i wants to add (home, list, data) in drawer navigation
*:- and then i wants to trigger tab change from drawer navigation

Comment: Hi @Farhan did you manage to solve the feature? I also have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this
```

App.js

```
 import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
 import NavigationService from './NavigationService';

    const TopLevelNavigator = createStackNavigator({
      /* ... */
    });

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(TopLevelNavigator);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  // ...

  render() {
    return (
      <AppContainer
        ref={navigatorRef => {
          NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

NavigationService.js

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

let _navigator;

function setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef) {
  _navigator = navigatorRef;
}

function navigate(routeName, params) {
  _navigator.dispatch(
    NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName,
      params,
    })
  );
}

// add other navigation functions that you need and export them

export default {
  navigate,
  setTopLevelNavigator,
};
```

Now you can access any routes from any js module

```
import NavigationService from 'path-to-NavigationService.js';

// ...

NavigationService.navigate('ChatScreen', { userName: 'Lucy' });
```